# grep -f generating unexpected output

Tags: grep

Using "grep -of file1.txt file2.txt" (file contents below), I get output:

```
and
if
pineapple
```

Why are 'dif' and 'for' missing? Do I have to use any other switches?

#### file1.txt

```
and
dif
for
if
apple
pineapple
```

#### file2.txt

```
andiforpineapple
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to re-search the input file for each pattern specified:

```
$ cat patterns.txt 
and
dif
for
if
apple
pineapple
$ cat source.txt 
andiforpineapple
$ while read; do grep -o -e"$REPLY" source.txt; done <patterns.txt
and
dif
for
if
apple
pineapple
```

However, this will have a different output line ordering than you apparently want, if the source file has more than one line.  Since you've not said what you're using this for, I don't know if that will work for your actual problem.

Comment: Hi Fred, My source.txt file contains a long single string of unknown DNA sequence, and the patterns.txt contains a several small known DNA fragments.

Comment: I'm very new to shell, so it would be kind of you to break it down. How does this work?                                              while read; do grep -o -e"$REPLY" source.txt; done <patterns.txt

Comment: @Naveen: I'd use a different tool for that kind of DNA matching. See "help while", "help read", and the "redirection" section in your sh's docs (e.g. man bash) for help on while, read, and <, respectively.

Comment: @Fred: "I'd use a different tool for that kind of DNA matching." What tools are used for this kind of job?

Comment: I understood how this works. Thanks!                           "while read; do grep -oe "$REPLY" source.txt; done < patterns.txt"

Comment: @Naveen: I don't do DNA matching, so I'm not really sure what other tools exist... :) But I have seen other questions about it, and this definitely feels like the wrong choice.

Comment: @Fred: Thanks for the info. I'll search for DNA matching tools on the net.

Answer (score 3):

Its like this:

```
andiforpineapple
  ^found and
   ^continuing search from i
    ^found if
     ^continuing search from o
       ^found pineapple
```

Comment: Hi Richard, Is there a way where I can force the search to start from the beginning of the string?

Comment: There are many implementations of grep. Which are you using?

Comment: I'm using this version for grep, GNU grep 2.6.3, and I'm running this os, Ubuntu 11.04

Comment: I don't see a command line option for this and unfortunately my Linux VM is dead at the moment. I would like to experiment with enhancing the regular expressions to use the \A anchor to match the start of the regex. You might try that. Here is [a good reference site on the web](http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html).